# Load page title in joomla 2.5 content

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, joomla2.5

I am looking for a way to load a page title in the Joomla 2.5 content for SEO purposes. I know in joomla you can use a function to load a module such as `{loadposition box1}`.

Is there a way to have a feature or does anyone know an extension so you can do something similar to this `{loadpagetitle}`.

This will save me hours of work.

Thanks.

Comment: what version of Joomla are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, install the [Direct PHP](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/4470) plugin and enable it.

Then copy and paste the following code into your article:

```
<?php 
   $mydoc = JFactory::getDocument();
   $mytitle = $mydoc->getTitle();
   echo $mytitle; 
?>
```

Make sure you use the `php` tags though.

Hope this helps. Regards.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. 

Took me a while to find a way to stop the JCE editor from removing the php tags. This can be done using this extension: [Sourcerer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/5051)

Comment: @uJoom: If this solved your problem, would you be so kind as to accept that answer by clicking the "tick" icon. thanks